# In Longtable, In multirow greater than \textwidth

Tags: line-breaking, longtable, multirow

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=5.5cm,marginparsep=1cm,outer=8cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

textwidth = 2.1cm + 2.8cm + 2.8cm + 2cm = 9.7cm

\begin{longtable}{|p{2.1cm}| p{2.8cm} |p{2.8cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Q CODES}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Q CODE} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{EXPLAIN}} \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{QOD} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Short Sentence, No Problem ( 9.7cm )}\\
                 & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Long Sentence, Long Sentence, Long Sentence Problem ( greater than 9.7cm )}\\
                 \cline{2-4}
                 & 0 Holland & 1 English & 2 France\\
                 & 3 Germany & 4 Greece & 5 Italia\\
                 & 6 Japan & 7 Norvia & 8 Russia\\
                 & 9 Espanol  & &\\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

displaying,
[image].

My problem, long sentence in longtable in multirow down to not go next line. That is row is greater than `\textwidth`. What will I do for the row line equal to `\textwidth` ? (Maybe, the answer it be easy. But I don't find.)

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{3}{p{7.6cm}|}{Long  Sentence ...}` instead of `l` column. 7.6cm is `2.8+2.8+2cm`, sum of last three column widths.

Comment: @HarishKumar - That should be `7.6cm+4\tabcolsep`, right?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I was typing from phone. It should be `\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr7.6cm+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{Long Sentence,...}` to be exact. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

use the parbox within multicolumn (adding 3 columns gives 7.6cm) like this:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

 \usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=5.5cm,marginparsep=1cm,outer=8cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

textwidth = 2.1cm + 2.8cm + 2.8cm + 2cm = 9.7cm

\begin{longtable}{|p{2.1cm}| p{2.8cm} |p{2.8cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Q CODES}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Q CODE} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{EXPLAIN}} \\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{QOD} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Short Sentence, No Problem ( 9.7cm )}\\
             & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\parbox{7.6cm}{Long Sentence, Long     Sentence, Long Sentence Problem ( greater than 9.7cm )}}\\
             \cline{2-4}
             & 0 Holland & 1 English & 2 France\\
             & 3 Germany & 4 Greece & 5 Italia\\
             & 6 Japan & 7 Norvia & 8 Russia\\
             & 9 Espanol  & &\\ 
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why use a parbox inside an `l` column instead of simply a `p` column?